# Mesos as a giant Linux box

Tags: distributed, distributed-computing, mesos, mesosphere

Is it possible to see all the mesos resources as a giant Linux box without custom code for the framework?

I am wondering, if I want to run a program using 2500tb of ram, can mesos abstract the master slave architecture away? Do I have to use custom code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write custom code. Mesos offers resources per agent (slave) basis and it is up to you how to coordinate binaries of your app running on different machines.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**: Mesos is a resource manager. Yes, it's a giant pool of resources. Although at a given time it will offer you only a subspace of all resources. Assuming that there are other users that might need some resources (don't worry there's a way how to utilize almost whole cluster).

[image: mesos scheduler]

**Q2**: Mesos is designed for a commodity hardware (many nodes, not a single giant HPC computer). A framework running on Mesos will be given a list resources (and slaves - worker nodes) and Mesos will execute a task within bound of given resources. This way you can start an MPI job or run a task on top of [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) which will handle the communication between nodes for you (but not Mesos itself).

**Q3**: You haven't specified what kind of task you'd like to compute. Spark comes with quite [a few examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples). You can run any of those without writing own code.

(Image credits: Malte Schwarzkopf, Google talk EuroSys 2013 in Prague)